# HTTP GET Response Redirect to .txt File

Tags: windows, http, batch-file, cmd, http-headers

I am trying to get a batch script which will do the below task.

1. Telnet to any website on port 80 (`telnet google.com 80`)
2. Execute HTTP GET request (`GET / HTTP/1.1` and `host: google.com`)
3. Redirect this output to the txt file.

I want the output in .txt files as shown below.

**Filename:** HTTP.txt

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ClUXV8WSEujI8Aep2L7oAQ
Content-Length: 261
Date: Wed, 20 Apr 2016 10:08:10 GMT
```

I want a batch file to auto input HTTP GET request and to set the HTTP host as well.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows machine 7 and 8.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use a batch file to establish a telnet session, send a command and have the output written to a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197376/is-it-possible-to-use-a-batch-file-to-establish-a-telnet-session-send-a-command)

Comment: Note this wont work for HTTPS

Comment: For HTTPS we need openssl

Comment: @AlexK. Its not only redirecting the output of telnet, instead I need the HTTP GET response recorded into the txt file. Its not a duplicate.

Comment: Building an HTTP stack in DOS batch? OMG, no. Use curl.exe or wget.exe (or download the source code and spend the next 30 years of your life trying to port these to DOS commands)

Comment: @symcbean, Let me try that, can I get the reference link please?

Comment: Curl lives at https://curl.haxx.se/ There are multiple ports of wget to MSWindows.Try http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Both curl and wget are built in Cygwin. It should be easy to get from http://cygwin.com/

Answer (score 0):

For http reques you can try  [winhttpjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/winhttpjs.bat) :

```
call winhttpjs.bat "http://google.com"  -method GET -reportfile reportfile.txt
```

though the format of the report is not exactly what you want you can rewrite it to fit your needs.