# Conditional statements in batch script using telnet command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Hi I don't know much about windows scripting but I have this case where I need to connect to my email server with different protocols for testing and I need to telnet those constantly which is very useless thing to do over and over again so I thought I should write a windows script so I can automate having to type the same thing over and over again.

**This is what I have so far:**

```
echo off
title Login to Mail using IMAP,POP3 and SMTP
echo Please enter the protocol required (POP3=1,IMAP=2,SMTP=3)&  
set /P id= Enter Value :
echo You have selected option :%id%
IF %id%==1(
   telnet <ip address> 110
   user user@example.com
   pass 123
)
IF %id%==2(
   telnet <ip address> 143
   a login user@example.com 123
)
IF %id%==3(
   telnet <ip address> 25
   helo r
   auth login
   <base64encodedusername>
   <base64encodedpassword>
)
```

The commands itself works as expected when I type them on cmd but it wouldn't work in the batch file. I'm assuming my syntax for conditional statements is the culprit but I am not sure. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with your conditional syntax. It has to be: `IF %id%==1 (` and so on with a space in front of the starting parenthesis. On [ss64](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) is a nice guide about condionally performing commands.

But also after the correction it will **not** work as the `telnet` command is **not** scribtable in Windows batch. That means after the first `telnet` command your batch script will stuck in that and no other command will be executed. Look at this [SO question about using telnet in batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197376/is-it-possible-to-use-a-batch-file-to-establish-a-telnet-session-send-a-command). There are several answers which show ways how to accomplish your task.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13200564/8051589) is working for several people according to the comments. It's using `start telnet.exe <IP>` and a Visual Basic Script (.vbs) to simulate key strokes. Quotation of that anwer:

> ### Batch File (named Script.bat ):
>
> ```
> :: Open a Telnet window
> start telnet.exe 192.168.1.1
> :: Run the script 
> cscript SendKeys.vbs
> ```
>
> ### Command File (named SendKeys.vbs ):
>
> ```
> set OBJECT=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
> WScript.sleep 50 
> OBJECT.SendKeys "mylogin{ENTER}" 
> WScript.sleep 50 
> OBJECT.SendKeys "mypassword{ENTER}"
> WScript.sleep 50 
> OBJECT.SendKeys " cd /var/tmp{ENTER}" 
> WScript.sleep 50 
> OBJECT.SendKeys " rm log_web_activity{ENTER}" 
> WScript.sleep 50 
> OBJECT.SendKeys " ln -s /dev/null log_web_activity{ENTER}" 
> WScript.sleep 50 
> OBJECT.SendKeys "exit{ENTER}" 
> WScript.sleep 50 
> OBJECT.SendKeys " "
> ```