# How to redirect or retrieve the output of a telnet process ran by a Powershell script?

Tags: powershell, telnet, vxworks

I am running a Powershell script that starts a telnet process which will connect on a client machine and run a command. The client machine's operating system is a personalized version of VxWorks, and the command I'm using on the telnet calls a tool developed internally on the machine:

```
mediaGet("gei",1)
```

I'd like to retrieve the output of the code and log it.

I've tried using the parameters -NoNewWindow and -RedirectStandardOutput on the Powershell script, but it only creates me an empty file which means it fails to retrieve the output.

Here is the Powershell script:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'telnet.exe' -ArgumentList '162.100.10.10'
[system.reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms")
$SendKeys = [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]
$sendkeys::SendWait('mediaGet{(}"gei"{)},1')
Start-Sleep -Seconds .5
$sendkeys::SendWait("{ENTER}")
Start-Sleep -Seconds .5
$sendkeys::SendWait("exit{ENTER}")
```

(Credits of this code go to the selected answer of this question [How to use a string variable as a telnet command in a vbscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56130037/how-to-use-a-string-variable-as-a-telnet-command-in-a-vbscript))

This is the output of the code

```
mediaGet("gei",1)
> media: 12345
> up: 1000 full duplex
```

I would like a text file at the end with the following lines:

```
media: 12345
up: 1000 full duplex
```

How can I get there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Komputer.

Yeppers, I missed getting back to you on the other Q&A. Good to see you are getting the response back now.

But even if that was in text file, you can just replace it after.

```
$TelnetData = @'
mediaGet("gei",1)
> media: 12345
> up: 1000 full duplex
'@ 
Clear-Host
$TelnetData -replace 'mediaGet|\("gei",1\)|> ', ''

# Results

media: 12345
up: 1000 full duplex
```

You can do this as the file is written as well, in normal cases.

However, on the redirect stuff, the common thing is,

> MS telnet doesn't use stdin/out.

So, approaches like this …

> For redirecting the output of a telnet session you can use the ...
>
> -f logfile
>
> ...argument and then importing it into a variable after you are done with it:
>
> $output = get-contents logfile

... are often brought up.

So, maybe this will get you where you want to be...

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'telnet.exe' -ArgumentList '162.100.10.10', '-f E:\Temp\log.txt'
[system.reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms")
$SendKeys = [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]
$sendkeys::SendWait('mediaGet{(}"gei"{)},1')
Start-Sleep -Seconds .5
$sendkeys::SendWait("{ENTER}")
Start-Sleep -Seconds .5
$sendkeys::SendWait("exit{ENTER}")
```

Once you do the above, then you can run the clean-up on it, using what I have above, via the [Get-Content and / or Set-Content cmdlets.](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2018/08/08/replace-text-with-powershell.aspx)

Of course I cannot access the IPA you list, nor do I have that MediaGet thing, but a quick test to a telnet capable site, will do this.

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'telnet.exe' -ArgumentList 'www.cyberciti.biz 80', '-f E:\Temp\log.txt'
[system.reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms")
$SendKeys = [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]
$sendkeys::SendWait("mediaGet'(''gei''',1)'")
Start-Sleep -Seconds .5
$sendkeys::SendWait("{ENTER}")
Start-Sleep -Seconds .5
$sendkeys::SendWait("exit{ENTER}")

# PowerShell Terminal output.

GAC    Version        Location                                                                                                                                 
---    -------        --------                                                                                                                                 
True   v4.0.30319     C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll 


# Telnet Window and text file content
Get-Content -Path 'E:\Temp\log.txt'

           HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
 Server: cloudflaree
 Date: Sat, 18 May 2019 08:39:59 GMTi
   Content-Type: text/html'Content-Type: text/html'

 Connection: close
 Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>e
  <body bgcolor="white">i
  <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
  <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>cloudflare</center>
</body>
</html>
```